# How to prove the parallel projection of an ellipsoid is an ellipse?

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry, surfaces, projective-geometry, ellipsoids

Take the following ellipsoid in implicit form as an example:

$$x^2 + 2 y^2 + 3 z^2 + x y + y z - 2 xz = 5$$

which shows:

[image]

[The parallel projection of the ellipsoid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573055/projection-of-ellipsoid) onto $xoy$ coordinate plane can be obtained as:

$$ 8 x^2 + 16 x y+23 y^2=60$$

[image]

Is it possible to prove:

1. The parallel projection of an ellipsoid is always an ellipse and how?

I guess this should be able to be generalized into:

2. the perspective projection of an ellipsoid is a conic curve.

How to prove it?

In prjective geometry, the quadratic form of conics is useful in such proof. This one seems a little more difficult.

Comment: A plane is defined by a vector $\mathbf{v}$ and a displacement $b$, ie $f(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{x}-b = 0$. The parallel projection amounts to removing any extension/support in the $\mathbf{v}$ direction. An ellipse can be parametrised in terms of its 3 principle axes and its axis lengths so you could transform into that representation and then apply a projection operator on each axis and, hopefully, you end up with the parametrisation for the interior and boundary of a 2d ellipse. It's a general approach, I think, but seems somewhat inelegant. Doesn't answer Part 2 either.

Comment: I have shown in my answer to this question :
 (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2438495) that there is a connection with a certain Schur complement  of the matrix of the ellipsoid.

Comment: It suffices to prove this for the unit sphere, since the general case can be transformed into this by an affinity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}$No claim of elegance, but Cartesian coordinates handle both questions, and the answers are "yes":

Up to translation, a general ellipsoid can be written in the form
$$
Ax^{2} + By^{2} + Cz^{2} + 2(Dxy + Exz + Fyz) = 1
\tag{1}
$$
for some positive-definite coefficient matrix
$$
\left[\begin{array}{@{}ccc@{}}
A & D & E \\
D & B & F \\
E & F & C \\
\end{array}\right].
$$

1. For definiteness, project the ellipsoid to the $(x, y)$-plane along the $z$-axis, and call the image the *shadow*. A point $p = (x, y, z)$ on the ellipsoid projects to the boundary of the shadow if and only if the tangent plane to the ellipsoid at $p$ is parallel to the $z$-axis, if and only if
   $$
   0 = \frac{\dd}{\dd z}\bigl(Ax^{2} + By^{2} + Cz^{2} + 2(Dxy + Exz + Fyz)\bigr)
     = 2(Ex + Fy + Cz).
   $$
   That is, the boundary of the ellipsoid's shadow is the shadow of a plane section of an ellipsoid (an ellipse), hence itself an ellipse.
2. Let $p_{0} = (x_{0}, y_{0}, z_{0})$ be an arbitrary point outside the ellipsoid. The ray from $p_{0}$ to a point $p = (x, y, z)$ on the ellipsoid is tangent to the ellipsoid if and only if the normal to the ellipsoid at $p$ is orthogonal to the ray, if and only if
   $$
   \nabla\bigl(Ax^{2} + By^{2} + Cz^{2} + 2(Dxy + Exz + Fyz)\bigr) \cdot (p - p_{0}) = 0,
   $$
   or (after dividing by $2$)
   $$
   (Ax + Dy + Ez)(x - x_{0}) + (Dx + By + Fz)(y - y_{0}) + (Ex + Fy + Cz)(z - z_{0}) = 0.
   \tag{2}
   $$
   After expanding, the second-order terms are precisely the left-hand side of (1); that is, (2) is again a linear equation. Consequently, the "horizon" of the ellipsoid from an arbitrary exterior center of projection is a plane section, so it projects to a (possibly degenerate) ellipse regardless of the "screen" plane.