# Showing positive definiteness in the projection of ellipsoid

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analytic-geometry, projective-geometry

I would like to show that the projection onto the $xoy$ plane of the centered ellipsoid given by the **definition** $$\mathbf{x'}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}=1$$ where we have a positive definite $$\mathbf{A}=
 \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
   a & d & e \\
   d & b & f \\
   e & f & c \\ 
   \end{array} \right]
$$ is an ellipse.
I know this has been covered in posts such as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1865188/how-to-prove-the-parallel-projection-of-an-ellipsoid-is-an-ellipse/), however, the answers there end by showing that the figure we need is the shadow of an ellipsoidal section (by a plane).  Then two statements are made that I know from intuition are true, but are not proved, namely.

1. An ellipsoidal section is an ellipse
2. The shadow of an ellipse is an
   ellipse.

Is there a way instead to show from the definition in 2-d space that it is indeed an ellipse in 2-D, the set of all $\mathbf{x}=(x,y)$ satisfying $$\mathbf{(x-v)'}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{(x-v)}=1$$ where $B$ is a positive definite $2 \times 2$ matrix and $\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is the center of the ellipse?

Here is what I have so far.  Similar to [Andrew Hwang's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1865188/how-to-prove-the-parallel-projection-of-an-ellipsoid-is-an-ellipse/) answer and [Christian Blatter's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573055/projection-of-ellipsoid) answer, I need that the z-component of $\nabla f$ should vanish on the curve I seek, where $f(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{x'}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}-1$.  Solving this along with the original equation of the ellipsoid, I get that the equation of the curve I seek is $$\mathbf{x'}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{x}=1$$ where $$\mathbf{B}=
 \left[\begin{array}{rr}
   (a-\frac{e^2}{c}) & (d-\frac{ef}{c}) \\
   (d-\frac{ef}{c}) & (b-\frac{f^2}{c}) \\
   \end{array} \right]$$
EDITED: The matrix B previously had a mistake in it - the off-diagonal element was stated as $(\frac{d}{2}-\frac{ef}{c})$ instead of $(d-\frac{ef}{c})$. Now fixed.
My **question is**, how do I show that this $B$ is positive definite?  The info I have is that from Sylvester's criterion applied to $A$, I know

1. $a > 0$
2. $ab - d^2 >0$
3. $a(bc-f^2) + d(ef-cd) + e(df-eb) >0$

I also know that $b$ and $c$ have to be positive.

Note: As an example of the kind of answer I was trying: I *was* able to prove for a different problem (that the section of the ellipsoid by a plane $z=l$ is an ellipse).  Here the curve is given by $$\mathbf{(x-v)'}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{(x-v)}=1-cl^2+\frac{l^2(af^2+be^2)}{ab-d^2}+\frac{efl^2d^3}{(ab-d^2)^2}$$ with $\mathbf{v}=(\frac{l(fd-eb)}{ab-d^2},\frac{l(ed-af)}{ab-d^2})$.In this case, $B$ was
$$\mathbf{B}=
 \left[\begin{array}{rr}
   a  & d \\
   d & b \\
   \end{array} \right]$$ and I know that is positive definite by Sylvester's criterion applied to the original $A$ matrix.

Comment: You have in fact much more inequalities like $ac-e^2>0$, $bc-f^2>0$, etc...

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks, but why do you say that?  Is it because of the use of Sylvester's criterion for positive **semi**definite matrices? In that case, ALL principal minors, and not just the *leading* principal minors are non-negative.  That would give me $ac-e^2 \geq 0$, $bc-f^2 \geq 0$ etc. Many more.  Of course, they are also true for a p.d. matrix like A, but I would end up being able to only prove positive semidefiniteness for B.  But we know that the shadow is an ellipse, i.e . B is actually p.d.

Comment: And indeed, only two quantities need to be shown as positive to show B is p.d..  One is $ac-e^2$.  And we already know that is $\geq 0$.  The other (call it G) is $G=(ac-e^2)(bc-f^2)-\frac{1}{4}(cd-2ef)^2$.  Intuition says that is is so.  Not only are the terms $ (ac-e^2)$ and $bc-f^2$ positive, they are also "big" relative to $(cd-2ef)^2$ because A is diagonally dominant ($a$, $b$ and $c$ are big relative to the other entries in A).  So G looks like it should be positive, but I am waving hands all over the place now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, a graphical illustration (Matlab program given below).
[image]

Answer to the question "Why is $B$ an spd (symmetric positive definite) matrix ?"

It is because $\mathbf{B}$ can be written, in a very natural way, as a "Schur complement"  (http://www.colorado.edu/engineering/CAS/courses.d/IFEM.d/IFEM.AppP.d/IFEM.AppP.pdf) with respect to matrix $\mathbf{A}$.

Let us partition matrix $\mathbf{A}$ into the following way:

$$\tag{1}\mathbf{A}=
 \left(\begin{array}{rr|r}
   a & d & e \\
   d & b & f \\ 
   \hline 
   e & f & c \\ 
   \end{array} \right)$$

yielding the following Schur complement:

$$\tag{2}\begin{pmatrix}a&d\\d&b\end{pmatrix}-\tfrac{1}{c}\begin{pmatrix}e\\f\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}e&f\end{pmatrix}=
 \left(\begin{array}{rr}
   a-\frac{e^2}{c} & d-\frac{ef}{c} \\
   d-\frac{ef}{c} & b-\frac{f^2}{c} \\
   \end{array} \right)$$

which coincides with the given matrix $\mathbf{B}$.

Now use the fact that a Schur complement of a spd matrix is itself spd (see "Properties" in  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement)).

**Edit: a complementary view** (see (https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/30588/147896)) is to interpret matrix $\mathbf{A}$ as a covariance matrix of a certain multivariate normal random variable $(X,Y,Z) \in \mathbb{R^3}$ and $\mathbf{B}$  (https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/30588/147896) as the covariance matrix associated with marginal distribution of $(X,Y) \in \mathbb{R^2}.$

Matlab program for the "cigar and smoke ring" figure:

> ```
> clear all;close all;hold on;axis equal;
> p=0.05;
> [X, Y, Z] = meshgrid(-1:p:1, -1:p:1, -1.5:p:1.5);
> r=1;a=3;b=1;c=2;d=2;e=1;f=2;
> A=[a b d
>    b c e
>    d e f];% caution: the coefficients' order has been changed
> isosurface(X, Y, Z, a*X.^2 + 2*b*X.*Y + c*Y.^2 +...
>   f*Z.^2 + 2*d*X.*Z+ 2*e*Y.*Z, r^2);
> camlight(60,0);shading flat;view([30,15]);
> S=A(1:2,1:2)-(1/f)*A(1:2,3)*A(3,1:2);%Schur complement
> u=S(1,1);v=S(2,2);w=S(2,1);
> ff = @(x,y) (u*x.^2 + v*y.^2 + 2*w*x.*y-1);% please note the -1
> ep=ezplot(ff);set(ep,'linecolor',[0.5,0.5,0.5],'linewidth',3);
> ```

Comment: Thanks! That's brilliant.  The matrix B did have just d and not d/2 as I'd first stated in error.  Thanks to your note, I've fixed it.  This completely answers the question.  I'd forgotten all about the existence of such a thing as the Schur complement.

Comment: Also, your answer helps solve this other question on MSE. I have updated the answer to that question with this Schur complement idea.  It was while trying to provide the answer to that question that I formulated m my own question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2431159/how-to-obtain-the-equation-of-the-projection-shadow-of-an-ellipsoid-into-2d-plan/2438682#2438682

Comment: And the correlation matrix interpretation of the Schur complement is pretty cool.