# Shadow of an arbitrarily oriented ellipsoid on the $xy$ plane

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, 3d, quadrics

Suppose I have an arbitrarily oriented ellipsoid, centered at $r_C$, and whose equation is given by:

$$ (r - r_C)^T Q (r - r_C) = 1$$

where the $3 \times 3 $ symmetric matrix $Q$ is known, and the $3 \times 1 $ vector $r_C$ is known, and the position vector $r = [x, y, z]^T$.  I want to find the equation of the projection (i.e. shadow outline) of this ellipsoid onto the $xy$ plane.  The projection is clearly an elliptical region, centered at $p_1$, and whose boundary is given by:

$$ (p -  p_1)^T Q_1 (p - p_1) = 1 $$

where $p = [x, y]^T $

So I'd like to find the steps to identify the $2 \times 2 $ symmetric matrix $Q_1$.

A detailed answer or hints on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe start by finding points of the ellipsoid where the tangent plane is perpendicular to the $xy$ plane.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2438709) where it is shown how to formulate the answer in terms of **Schur's complement** matrix.

Comment: Thanks @jeanmarie for the citation.