# Orthogonal projection of an ellipsoïd from N to 2 dimensional space

Tags: projection, projection-matrices, ellipsoids

Suppose we have a $N\times N$ symmetric-positive-definite matrix $A$, representing an ellipsoïd in $N$ dimensional space. How to find the matrix $A_{xy}$ corresponding to orthogonal projection of ellispoid on $xy$-plan ?

I have already consulted this pages, they were not that helpful:

[How to obtain the equation of the projection/shadow of an ellipsoid into 2D plane?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2431159)
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1866994/1054066

**edit** after some suggestions :
Schur complement method seems to work in 3 dimensions:

here's an exemple:

suppose $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0.5 & -1 \\ 0.5 & 2 & 0.5 \\ -1 & 0.5 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$

[image]

than Schur complement method says that $A_{xy} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0.5 \\ 0.5 & 2\end{pmatrix} - \frac{1}{3} \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0.5\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0.5\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0.67 & 0.67 \\ 0.67 & 1.92\end{pmatrix}$

Here's the result :

[image]

but I dont see how to make it work in 5 dimansional space. The goal is to project 5D-ellipsoid on xy-plane.

Comment: Take a look at the answer I gave [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2438709/305862) which amounts to say that you have to take the $2 \times 2$ "Schur's complement" (corresponding to the pair of variables of the plane you want to project onto) in the $n \times n$ matrix $A$.

Comment: @JeanMarie I have tried to use Schur's complement method but it doesn't seem to work. I edited my post showing an exemple.

Comment: I am going to have a look at your computations. Any Schur's complement issued from a positive definite matrix _should be_ definite positive...

Comment: I see a first problem: your $3 \times 3$ matrix isn't symmetric...

Comment: @JeanMarie, sorry it's a typo, actually the matrix is symmetric, I didn't copy it correctly here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose M is a ***symmetric*** $N \times N$ matrix representing an ellipsoid : $$X^T M X = 1$$ with $X \in \mathbb{R}^N$.

**1st method of projection** : using a projection matrix P
$$P_{xy} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & ... & 0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \overrightarrow{i} \\ \overrightarrow{j} \end{pmatrix}$$ where $\overrightarrow{i}$ and $\overrightarrow{j}$ cartesian base vectors for $xy$-plane. For exemple if we want to project an object of 7-dimensional to 3-dimensional space (on any 3 arbitrary axis) than the projection matrix will take the form : $$ P_{7D \to 3D} = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0&0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix} \overrightarrow{e_1} \\ \overrightarrow{e_5}\\ \overrightarrow{e_3} \end{pmatrix}$$

The projection of M on $xy$-plane is an ellipse given by $M_{xy}$ : $$ M_{xy} = (P_{xy} M^{-1} P_{xy}^T)^{-1} $$

**2nd method** : using the Schur complement.

First we divide the matrix M into 4 blocs as follows : $$ M = \begin{pmatrix} 
A & B \\ D & C \end{pmatrix}$$ than Schur's complement gives $M_{xy}$ :

$$ M_{xy} = A - BC^{-1}D $$

---

here's an exemple :

$$ M = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0.5 & -1 \\ 0.5 & 2 & 0.5 \\ -1 & 0.5 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$$

1st method: projection matrix
$$P_{xy} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$M_{xy} = (P_{xy} M^{-1} P_{xy}^T)^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 0.67 & 0.67 \\ 0.67 & 1.92\end{pmatrix}$$

2nd method : Schur complement
$$M_{xy} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0.5 \\ 0.5 & 2 \end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0.5 \end{pmatrix} \frac{1}{3} \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0.5 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0.67 & 0.67 \\ 0.67 & 1.92\end{pmatrix}$$

[image]

Comment: In the case of $5 \times 5$ matrix, partition it into $M = \begin{pmatrix} 
A & B \\ D & C \end{pmatrix}$ where now $S=A-DC^{-1}B$ with $A,C$ with dimensions $2 \times 2$ and $3 \times 3$ resp.

Comment: @JeanMarie, I finally got the results 