# How do I project a hyperellipsoid onto a plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections

I know how to project a 3d ellipsoid onto a plane (e.g: [Projection of ellipsoid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573055/projection-of-ellipsoid)).

I was wondering if there was some way of projecting onto the coordinate planes, an $n$-dimensional hyperellipsoid of the form $z^TCz = k$, where $z$ is a vector of $n$ coordinates, $C$ is an $n$x$n$ symmetric positive definite matrix and $k$ is a positive constant.

Comment: What sort of projection do you have in mind?

Comment: Good question. So for 2d ellipsoids, the projections that I am interested in are the projections obtained by cutting the coordinate axes with horizontal and vertical tangents to the ellipsoids. For 3d ellipsoids, I would use tangent planes. I am looking for an n-dimensional analog of that. I am not sure how to go about it though.