# Projection of High Dimensional Ellipsoid onto the Hyperplane

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, surfaces

Find the projection of the ellipsoid:

$
\mathcal{E}:= \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n, y \in \mathbb{R}^m \left| \begin{pmatrix} x^T & y^T \end{pmatrix} \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} P_1 & P_2 \\ P_2^T & P_3 \end{pmatrix}}_{P} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}=1   \right. \right\},
$
onto the $x$-hyperplane. The matrix $P \in \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ is positive definite; thus, $P_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $P_3 \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ are nonsingular.

Professor Christian Blatter answered a similar question here: [Projection of ellipsoid](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/573055). Following his approach, I propose the following solution. Please let me know if you find something wrong. I am not very knowledgeable in these type of Geometric problems.

The ellipsoid $\mathcal{E}$ can be regarded as the level set at the origin of the function:

$F(x,y):= \begin{pmatrix} x^T & y^T \end{pmatrix} P \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} -1$,

that is, $
\mathcal{E}= \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n, y \in \mathbb{R}^m \left|F(x,y)=0    \right. \right\}$. Let $\mathcal{E}'$ be the projection of $\mathcal{E}$ onto the $x$-hyperplane. The points  $p\in \mathcal{E}$ that generate the boundary $\partial \mathcal{E}'$ are characterized by the property that the tangent hyperplane at $p$ is parallel to the $y$-hyperplane. Thus, the normal hyperplane $n_p$ at $p$ is perpendicular to the $y$-hyperplain or, in other words, the $y$-component of $n_p$ are equal to the $m$-dimensional zero vector $\mathbf{0}_m$. The gradient of $F(x,y)$ is given by

$\nabla F(x,y) = 2P\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2P_1x + 2P_2y \\ 2P_2^Tx + 2P_3y \end{pmatrix}$,

and $n_p$ is given by $\nabla F(p)$. The $y$-component of $\nabla F(p)$ is given by $2P_2^Tx + 2P_3y$. Therefore, we can say that the points $p$ in question lie on the hyperplane $2P_2^Tx + 2P_3y=\mathbf{0}_m$. It follows that the points $(x,y) \in \mathcal{E}$ producing the projection boundary are the points with $2P_2^Tx + 2P_3y=\mathbf{0}_m$, i.e., the points $(x,y)$ satisfying:

$F(x,-(P_3)^{-1}P_2^Tx) = x^T\left( P_1 - P_2P_3^{-1}P_2^T   \right)x - 1$.

Hence, the projection $\mathcal{E}'$ is given by

$
\mathcal{E}' = \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \left| x^T\left( P_1 - P_2P_3^{-1}P_2^T   \right)x = 1   \right. \right\}.
$

Interestingly, the matrix $\left( P_1 - P_2P_3^{-1}P_2^T   \right)$ that generates the ellipsoid $\mathcal{E}'$ is the Schur complement of the block $P_3$ of the matrix $P$.

Comment: First of all, this is not of research level, and should have been posted on [Math.SE], like the question that you link to. Second, you should have at least split your post into a question and an answer and posted them separately.