# Projective Mapping of translated Quadric

Tags: conic-sections, projective-geometry, quadrics

### Question

I have an ellipsoid described by a covariance matrix $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$ and its centroid location $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$ (yes; notation from statistics as I want to interpret it as a Gaussian later). I want to obtain the projection of it in a geometry given by the projective mapping $P \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times4}$. Within the constraint geometrical setup detailed later, i believe the conic projection should be an ellipse again and that should be expressable with a 2D ($\Sigma, \mu$).

Available as [Notebook](https://gist.github.com/maxrohleder/8fc2950a7fe54fc787ea07331312c33f).

### Approach so far

I followed [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2757064) but had no luck transferring the approach to a non-parrallel projection using a quadric where the translation is non-zero.

#### homogenous represention of quadric

I start by expressing the ellipsoid as a quadric following the answer in [[4]](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3201266/1018514). A quadric is described by a symmetrical $4\times4$ matrix $Q$:

$$\hat{\mathbf x}^T\mathtt Q\hat{\mathbf x} = \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf x&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\mathtt A & \mathbf b \\ \mathbf b^T & c\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf x\\1\end{bmatrix} = 0.$$

I plug in the covariance and mean vector for the respective variables in $Q$ to yield:

$$\mathtt Q = \begin{bmatrix}\mathtt \Sigma & \mathbf \mu \\ \mathbf \mu^T & -1\end{bmatrix}.$$

#### construction of projection matrix

I want to create projection matrices that describe a projective geometry given by the focal length $f$, the pierce point $(p_x, p_y)$ the source position $C$ and a camera rotation $R_c$. I obtain the projection matrix $P$ following [[1]](https://ksimek.github.io/2013/08/13/intrinsic/):

$$
P=
\begin{bmatrix}
f & 0 & p_{x} \\
0 & f & p_{y} \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\times
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\times
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathtt R_{c}^T & -R_{c}^TC \\
\mathtt 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

#### projection of quadric

I followed the answer in [[4]](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2757064) which quotes the book [[2]](http://www.r-5.org/files/books/computers/algo-list/image-processing/vision/Richard_Hartley_Andrew_Zisserman-Multiple_View_Geometry_in_Computer_Vision-EN.pdf) Hartley Zisserman chapter 8.3 to get this simple formula for the projection of the quadric $Q$ onto the conic $C$:

$$\mathtt C^*=\mathtt P\mathtt Q^*\mathtt P^T$$

The dual-forms (asterisk) are obtained by the use of the inverse ($C^{*}=C^{-1}$):

$$C = (PQ^{-1}P^T)^{-1}$$

### Example

The projective geometry is given by $f=3718$, $C=[0, 0, -1987]^T$, $R=I$. This describes a camera looking into positive z-direction sitting at some point on the z-axis.

I define an ellipsoid aligned with the coordinate axis with dimensions $(300, 100, 100)$ and position $(255.5, 255.5, 255.5)$:

$$\mathtt Q =
\begin{bmatrix}
300 & 0 & 0 & 255.5 \\
0 & 100 & 0 & 255.5 \\
0 & 0 & 100 & 255.5 \\
255.5 & 255.5 & 255.5 & -1
\end{bmatrix},$$

[3d and 2d verification plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4BaU.png)

To verify the formulation of the quadric, I generate a set of points on the unit-sphere and multiply them with the quadric $\hat{x}'=Q\hat{x}$. The set of points traces out the desired ellipsoid nicely.

To verify the projection matrices, I project these points onto the detector. The resulting scatter plot looks convincing.

To test if the computed Conic is valid, I create points on the unit-circle and multiply them with the conic $\hat{u}'=C\hat{u}$. This however looks false. I observe, that the Covariance of the projected conic is almost zer0.

Does someone have a clue what could be going wrong? Is the theory consistent, or am I missing something important?

#### Sources

[1]: Construct Projection Matrix, https://ksimek.github.io/2012/08/22/extrinsic/

[2]: Hartley & Zisserman, *Multiple View Geometry In Computer Vision*, 2004

[3]: Project Quadric onto Conic, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2757064

[4]: Construct Quadric from Cov and mean, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3201266/1018514

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general the approach $C = (P^{\top}Q^{-1}P)^{-1}$ is valid, however there are some intricacies that need to be dealt with carefully:

1. Converting a 3d Gaussian $(\Sigma, \mu)$ into a Quadric ($4\times4$ symmetric matrix $Q$)
2. Converting the Conic ($3\times3$ symmetric matrix $C$) back to a Gaussian $(\Sigma', \mu')$
3. Sampling the 3D and 2D Gaussians

#### 1. Quadric from Gaussian

I cite [my other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4451323/convert-ellipsoid-from-cov-and-mean-to-quadric-representation) that deals with this. To describe the surface-ellipsoid of a 3D Gaussian thresholded at $\sigma$, use this parametrization of $Q$:

$$(x-\mu)^\top\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)-\sigma=0$$

$$Q = \begin{bmatrix}A & b \\ b^⊤ & c\end{bmatrix},  \quad
\hat{x}^{\top}Q\hat{x}=0,  \quad
\hat{x}=[x^{\top},1]^{\top}$$

$$A=\Sigma^{-1}, \quad b=-A\mu , \quad c=\mu^⊤\Sigma^{-1}\mu-\sigma$$

#### 2. Gaussian from Conic

The conic $C$ is derived from $Q$ by $C = (P^{\top}Q^{-1}P)^{-1}$. To represent is as a 2D Gaussian distribution $(\Sigma', \mu')$ thresholded at $\sigma$, we derive the parameters analogously to above.

$$C = \begin{bmatrix}a&b/2&d/2\\b/2&c&e/2\\d/2&e/2&f\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}A'&b'\\b'^{\top} & f\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\Sigma=A^{-1}, \quad \mu =-\Sigma b', \quad \sigma = \mu^{\top} \Sigma^{-1} \mu - f$$

What I have overlooked so far is to scale the Covariance by $\sigma$ (at least thats my interpretation of it, but please correct me if I am wrong):

$$\Sigma'=\Sigma\sigma$$

#### 3. Sampling the $\sigma$-surface/line of a 3D/2D Gaussian

Finding points on the surface of a 3D Gaussian or analogously the circumference of a 2D Gaussian can be done by using the Cholesky Factor of the Covariance. I like to think of it as the square root for matrices:

$$\Sigma=LL^{\top}$$

Points on the Ellipsoid/Ellipse at $\sigma=1$ can now be obtained by transforming points on the unit-sphere/circle $\hat{x}$ like so:

$$x=L\hat{x}+\mu'$$

Sampling directly using $\Sigma$ will also produce an ellipsoid/ellipse, but the radii of the resulting object will be squared and thus not correspond with the formulation of the quadric/conic $Q$/$C$.